# CSRF Forbbiden 403

Tags: django

index.html:

```
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  you are logged in!
  {% else %}
  <h3>Login</h3>
  <form action="/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" />
  <label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" />
  <p><input type="submit" value="Login →"></p>
  </form>
  {% endif %}
```

views.py:

```
def main(request):

    respuesta=""
    salida=""
    lista=Hotel.objects.all()

    listauser=Users.objects.all()

    if len(lista) == 0:
        print("Parsing....")
        theParser = make_parser()
        theHandler = myContentHandler()
        theParser.setContentHandler(theHandler)
        fil = urllib2.urlopen( 'http://www.esmadrid.com/opendata/alojamientos_v1_es.xml')
        theParser.parse(fil)

    template = get_template("index.html")
    if request.user.is_authenticated():

        return HttpResponse(template.render({'lista':lista[mini:maxi],'user':request.user.username,'listausers':listauser,'condicion':""}))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Not logged in"+"<a href=login"+"> Log in</a>")
```

Me da un fallo CSRF Forbbiden , ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?.

Comment: Indica si en tu configuración usas `DEBUG=False` y si tienes configurado `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. Coloca también el mensaje de error con la información relevante.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que validar los siguientes puntos

1. Tu navegador acepta cookies
2. 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' esta incluido en tu archivo de configuración settings.py
3. Asegurarse que puedes pasar el csrf token de django.core.context_processors.csrf al context manager